# template specialization according to sizeof type

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to provide a templated function, that varies its implementation (->specialization) according to the sizeof the template type.

Something similar to this (omitted typecasts), but without the if/elseif:

```
template<class T>
T byteswap(T & swapIt)
{
    if(sizeof(T) == 2)
    {
        return _byteswap_ushort (swapIt);
    }
    else if(sizeof(T) == 4)
    {
        return _byteswap_ulong(swapIt);
    }
    else if(sizeof(T) == 8)
    {
        return _byteswap_uint64(swapIt);
    }
            throw std::exception();
}
```

I know there are many roads to reach my goal, but since I try to learn about `SFINAE` and `type traits` I'm particularly interested in solutions using those techniques to decide at compile time which specialization to choose and which calls are not admitted.

Perhaps implementing a class trait is_4ByteLong and using boost::enable_if...

I have to admit, I'm stuck right now, so I thank you for any help or advice

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need SFINAE or type traits. Vanilla template specialization is enough. Of course it must be specialized on structs as C++(98) doesn't support function template partial specialization.

```
template <typename T, size_t n>
struct ByteswapImpl
/*
{
  T operator()(T& swapIt) const { throw std::exception(); }
}
*/    // remove the comments if you need run-time error instead of compile-time error.
;

template <typename T>
struct ByteswapImpl<T, 2> {
  T operator()(T& swapIt) const { return _byteswap_ushort (swapIt); }
};

// ...

template <typename T>
T byteswap(T& swapIt) { return ByteswapImpl<T, sizeof(T)>()(swapIt); }
```

Comment: Nice answer but I would not make a default implementation of `ByteswapImpl`. That way, you'll just get a compile error if the needed specialization does not exist.

Comment: And the function can be static so that no object has to be created (similar to `boost::numeric_cast` and `boost::numeric_conververt`).

Comment: I was under the impression that only function template *partial* specialization isn't supported... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Job: you're right, but since `T` isn't precised here we are effectively speaking about partial specialization.

Comment: @Job: Thanks, added back the "partial".

Answer (score 4):

Simply make an auxiliary class that takes the size as a template argument:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>


template<std::size_t Size>
struct ByteSwapper { };

template<>
struct ByteSwapper<2> {
  static unsigned short swap(unsigned short a) {
    return 2 * a;
  }
};

template<typename T>
T byteswap(const T& a) {
  return ByteSwapper<sizeof(T)>::swap(a);
}


int main() {
  unsigned short s = 5;
  std::cout << byteswap(s) << std::endl;
  unsigned int i = 7;
  // std::cout << byteswap(i) << std::endl; // error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of demonstrating `enable_if` in action, since you spoke about it:

```
template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if_c< sizeof(T) == 2, T >::type
swapIt(T& rhs) { return _byteswap_short(rhs); }

template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if_c< sizeof(T) == 4, T >::type
swapIt(T& rhs) { return _byteswap_long(rhs); }
```

etc...

And of course, instead of throwing, there is just no implementation if the type doesn't meet any of the requirement and thus you have a compile time error.

Two notes:

- Use of `typename` and `::type` are mandatory
- I used `enable_if_c` because my expression evaluates to a boolean value directly, whereas `enable_if` requires a type containing a `::value` member which is a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose the following method:
Its benefit is that you don't have to `throw` an exception if the operand isn't of the valid size. It just won't link. So that you have the error checking at build time.

```
template<int size>
void byteswapInPlace(void* p);

template<> void byteswapInPlace<1>(void* p) { /* do nothing */ }

template<> void byteswapInPlace<2>(void* p)
{
    _byteswap_ushort((ushort*) p);
}

template<> void byteswapInPlace<4>(void* p)
{
    _byteswap_ulong((ulong*) p);
}

template<> void byteswapInPlace<8>(void* p)
{
    _byteswap_uint64((uint64*) p);
}


template<class T>
T byteswap(T & swapIt)
{
    byteswapInPlace<sizeof(T)>(&swapIt);
    return swapIt;
}
```

Comment: You could instead put some sort of static assertion (e.g `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`) in the base case. No need to wait until linking to get an error.

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is what I'd do: default imlpementation which generates a compiler error.