# Exclude part of function template during compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, bit-shift, compile-time

Please consider the following code. It is a function template that operates on the type `T` depending from its bit width. The actual code is more complex but that is irrelevant:

```
template <typename T> T MyFunc(T t)
{
   constexpr const uint8_t typeBitCount = sizeof(T)*8;

   // more code here that works fine for all widths

   if (typeBitCount >= 32)
   {
      if (...)
      {
         return t >> 16; // warning right shift count >= width of type
      }

      if (typeBitCount >= 64)
      {
         if (...)
         {
            return t >> 32; // warning right shift count >= width of type
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I use this with 8 bit types too. In that case I get warnings (see commented lines). Unfortunately C++ isn't able to evaluate the `if` condition during compiletime even when using `constexpr`. I could probably suppress the warnings but that seems hacky to me. I would prefer to exclude the problematic code at compile time.

How can this be solved (possibly without breaking the code in pieces and without creating redundancies)?

I am using GCC 5.4.0.

Comment: All of the code has to be compiled. The selection depending on `typeBitCount` only happens at run-time, not compile-time. Therefore you get the warnings when the compiler comes to those lines.

Comment: That is totally clear. The question is how to solve this as clean as possible.

Comment: If you have a C++14 compiler you might be able to make the whole function a `constexpr` function and have it evaluated a compile-time (depending on the "more code here..." part). That might solve some of your problems. Or you could specialize the function for 8-bit types, and put the common "more code here..." part in a separate function.

Comment: Before C++14, you will need to introduce a templated helper class, where one of the template parameters is an integral value equal to `sizeof(T)` (or `sizeof(T)*8`), and (possibly static) member functions to do required operations.   Then use template partial specialisation to instantiate that class and its functions for each valid value of `sizeof(T)`.    That means you can't get away "without breaking the code into pieces", but that's a cost of seeking a compile-time mechanism - template (partial) specialisation is the basic compile time mechanism for what, at run time, is done using an `if`

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Using C++14 I can actually can make the function constexpr. However the warning remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this without any templates. I used plain overloading instead. I broke the code into pieces and a single function for each type, cascading theses function from 64 bit width to 8 bit width.

Answer (score 1):

I'd calculate the problematic shift so that:

- when the shift is to be executed, it has the required value 32,
- if it should not be executed, it has some small value 0:

  ```
  ....
  constexpr uint8_t shift2 = (typeBitCount >= 64) ? 32 : 0;
  ....
  if (typeBitCount >= 64)
    {
       if (...)
       {
          return t >> shift2;
       }
    }
  ....
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial template specialization similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529263/template-specialization-according-to-sizeof-type) to implement the function dependent on the type size using functors:

```
// Base implementation for unsupported size and type.
template <typename T, size_t TSize>
class MyFuncImpl;

// 32-bit specialization.
template <typename T>
struct MyFuncImpl<T, 4>
{
    T operator()(const T t) const
    {
        return t >> 16;
    }
};

// 64-bit specialization.
template <typename T>
struct MyFuncImpl<T, 8>
{
    T operator()(const T t) const
    {
        return t >> 32;
    }
};

// Calling this functor will calculate the correct bit-shift at compile time and not emit warnings.
template <typename T>
T MyFunc(const T t)
{
    return MyFuncImpl<T, sizeof(T)>()(t);
}
```

You can also add extra specializations for 8-bit and 16-bit types. You would use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t test1 = 1235434;
    std::cout << MyFunc(test1) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```